# I am very new to programming. I am implementing First Come First Serve(FCFS)

Tags: java

I am very new to programming and to stackOverflow. I am implementing First Come First Serve(FCFS).But I am getting array index out of bound exception, while entering input in []ArrivalTime I can be a silly mistake but i can not figure out why ,Please help me

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FCFS_Practice {
    public static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int numberOfProcess = 0;
    int[]ProcessID = new int[numberOfProcess];
    int[]ArrivalTime  = new int[numberOfProcess];
    int[]BurstTime = new int[numberOfProcess];
    int[]CompletionTime = new int[numberOfProcess];
    int[]TurnAroundTime = new int[numberOfProcess];
    int[]WaitingTime = new int[numberOfProcess];
    float avgWaitingTime = 0,avgTurnAroundTime = 0;

    public void takeInput(){
        System.out.println("Enter the number of process: ");
        numberOfProcess = scanner.nextInt();
    }
    public void inputArrivalAndBurstTime(){
        for(int i = 0;i < numberOfProcess;i++){
            System.out.printf("Enter Arrival Time for Process %d: ",i+1);
            ArrivalTime[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine(); // Buffer Flush
            System.out.printf("Enter Burst Time for Process %d: ",i+1);
            BurstTime[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine(); // Buffer flush
            ProcessID[i] = i+1;
        }
    }
    public void calculateCompletionTime(){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < numberOfProcess ; i++){
            if(i==0){
                CompletionTime[0]=BurstTime[0];
            } else if (ArrivalTime[i]<CompletionTime[i-1]) {
                CompletionTime[i]=CompletionTime[i-1]+BurstTime[i];
            } else {
                 CompletionTime[i]=ArrivalTime[i]+BurstTime[i];
            }
        }
    }
    public void calculateTurnAroundAndWaitingTime(){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < numberOfProcess ; i++){
            TurnAroundTime[i]=CompletionTime[i]+ArrivalTime[i];
            WaitingTime[i]=TurnAroundTime[i]-BurstTime[i];
        }
    }
    public void getAvgWaitingTimeAndAvgTurnAroundTime(){
        for(int i = 0 ; i<numberOfProcess;i++){
            avgTurnAroundTime+=TurnAroundTime[i];
            avgWaitingTime+=WaitingTime[i];
        }
        avgWaitingTime = avgWaitingTime/numberOfProcess;
        avgTurnAroundTime = avgTurnAroundTime/numberOfProcess;
    }
    public void getTable(){
        System.out.println("ProcessNo.  ArrivalTime  BurstTime  CompletionTime  TurnAroundTime  WaitingTime");
        for(int i = 0 ; i < numberOfProcess ; i++){
            System.out.println(ProcessID[i]+"\t\t"+ArrivalTime[i]+"\t\t"+BurstTime[i]+"\t\t"+CompletionTime[i]+"\t\t\t"+TurnAroundTime[i]+"\t\t\t"+WaitingTime[i]);
        }
    scanner.close();
    }
}

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1CEd.png)
```

Comment: your declared :   static int numberOfProcess = 0; and then using it to create arrays, this creates Arrays of 0 length, thats why "Out of bounds"  exception is thrown. Set numberOfProcess to atleast 1 or to the number of processes you want to enter

Comment: so sir i am using takeinput function to change the class variable  number of process, so why it is not working and thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You asked

> Why getting IndexOutOfBoundsException with in shared snippet.

You declared `static int numberOfProcess = 0;` and creating many arrays of length 0, so every time you try to access those array you will get `IndexOutOfBoundsException` which thrown to indicate that an index of some sort (such as to an array, to a string, or to a vector) is out of range.

**Workaround** ?

- Many ways to resolve it, one practice is to declare your array implementation size after reading `numberOfProcess` through your scanner and make their pointer static.

```html
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter the number of process: ");
        numberOfProcess = scanner.nextInt();
        processID = new int[numberOfProcess];
        arrivalTime  = new int[numberOfProcess];
        burstTime = new int[numberOfProcess];
        completionTime = new int[numberOfProcess];
        turnAroundTime = new int[numberOfProcess];
        waitingTime = new int[numberOfProcess];
        ...
    }
    static int[] processID;
    static int[] arrivalTime;
    static int[] burstTime;
    static int[] completionTime;
    static int[] turnAroundTime;
    static int[] waitingTime;
    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    ...
```

- Other practice is just change the declaration type to list and traverse/allocate values accordingly.

**Extra point**

- Please follow language model standards as well, like naming [convention](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html)

Answer (score 0):

An ordinary array can not be resized once declared. So use ArrayList instead

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FCFS_Practice {
    public static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int numberOfProcess = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> processID = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<Integer> arrivalTime = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<Integer> burstTime = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<Integer> completionTime = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<Integer> turnAroundTime = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<Integer> waitingTime = new ArrayList();
    
   
   
    float avgWaitingTime = 0,avgTurnAroundTime = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
      {
          FCFS_Practice practice = new FCFS_Practice();
          practice.takeInput();
          practice.initializeArrayList();
          practice.inputArrivalAndBurstTime();
          practice.calculateCompletionTime();
          practice.calculateTurnAroundAndWaitingTime();
          practice.getTable();
          
      }
    public void initializeArrayList()
    {
        for(int i=0; i < numberOfProcess;i++)
        {
            processID.add(0);
    arrivalTime.add(0);
    burstTime.add(0);
     completionTime.add(0);
     turnAroundTime.add(0);
     waitingTime.add(0);
        }
    }
    public void takeInput(){
        System.out.println("Enter the number of process: ");
        numberOfProcess = scanner.nextInt();
    }
    public void inputArrivalAndBurstTime(){
        for(int i = 0;i < numberOfProcess;i++){
            System.out.printf("Enter Arrival Time for Process %d: ",i+1);
            arrivalTime.set(i,  scanner.nextInt());
            scanner.nextLine(); // Buffer Flush
            System.out.printf("Enter Burst Time for Process %d: ",i+1);
            burstTime.set(i, scanner.nextInt());
            scanner.nextLine(); // Buffer flush
            processID.set(i, i+1);
        }
    }
    public void calculateCompletionTime(){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < numberOfProcess ; i++){
            if(i==0){
                completionTime.set(0,burstTime.get(0));
            } else if (arrivalTime.get(i)<completionTime.get(i-1)) {
                completionTime.set(i,completionTime.get(i-1)+burstTime.get(i));
            } else {
                 completionTime.set(i, arrivalTime.get(i)+burstTime.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
    public void calculateTurnAroundAndWaitingTime(){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < numberOfProcess ; i++){
            turnAroundTime.set(i,completionTime.get(i)+arrivalTime.get(i));
            waitingTime.set(i,turnAroundTime.get(i)-burstTime.get(i));
        }
    }
    public void getAvgWaitingTimeAndAvgTurnAroundTime(){
        for(int i = 0 ; i<numberOfProcess;i++){
            avgTurnAroundTime+=turnAroundTime.get(i);
            avgWaitingTime+=waitingTime.get(i);
        }
        avgWaitingTime = avgWaitingTime/numberOfProcess;
        avgTurnAroundTime = avgTurnAroundTime/numberOfProcess;
    }
    public void getTable(){
        System.out.println("ProcessNo.  ArrivalTime  BurstTime  CompletionTime  TurnAroundTime  WaitingTime");
        for(int i = 0 ; i < numberOfProcess ; i++){
            System.out.println(processID.get(i)+"\t\t"+arrivalTime.get(i)+"\t\t"+burstTime.get(i)+"\t\t"+completionTime.get(i)+"\t\t\t"+turnAroundTime.get(i)+"\t\t\t"+waitingTime.get(i));
        }
    scanner.close();
    }
}
```

You have started variable names with Upper case alphabet.. [java coding conventions](https://www.theserverside.com/feature/Java-naming-conventions-explained#:%7E:text=For%20variables%2C%20the%20Java%20naming,a%20lower%20camel%20case%20syntax.)

I have changed variable names accordingly

[ArrayList explained](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arraylist.asp)